# TSQL\XPATH - Getting Proper XPath-Index of element on CROSS APPLY node(child)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

Using xpath `child.value('for $i in . return count(../../*[. << $i])', 'int')` will give me the index of a node in an XML, by counting the number of adjacent nodes in the parent node, which occur before the current node. This works great, but I need to group\reset the index count by the **NODE-NAME**.

*(In the below example, I'm querying the index as a varchar so I can concatonate a string with its content)*

```
DECLARE @x XML = '
<Vitals>
    <BP>
        <Value>120/80</Value>
        <Time>02:00:05</Time>
    </BP>
    <BP>
        <Value>140/90</Value>
        <Time>02:10:01</Time>
    </BP>
    <BP>
        <Value>120/80</Value>
        <Time>02:15:05</Time>
    </BP>
    <HR>
        <Value>80</Value>
        <Time>02:00:12</Time>
    </HR>
    <HR>
        <Value>84</Value>
        <Time>02:10:12</Time>
    </HR>
</Vitals>'

SELECT '/' + child.value('local-name(../..)', 'varchar(max)') + '/' + child.value('local-name(..)', 'varchar(max)') + '[' + child.value('for $i in . return count(../../*[. << $i])', 'varchar(max)') + ']' AS NodePath
    ,child.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') AS NodeName
    ,child.value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS NodeValue
FROM (
    SELECT @x AS import_data
    ) i
CROSS APPLY i.import_data.nodes('/Vitals/*/*') AS nodes(child)
WHERE LEN(cast(child.query('./*') AS VARCHAR(max))) = 0
ORDER BY child.value('for $i in . return count(../../*[. << $i])', 'int')
```

Returns:

```
/Vitals/BP[1]   Value   120/80
/Vitals/BP[1]   Time    02:00:05
/Vitals/BP[2]   Value   140/90
/Vitals/BP[2]   Time    02:10:01
/Vitals/BP[3]   Value   120/80 
/Vitals/BP[3]   Time    02:15:05
/Vitals/HR[4]   Value   80 
/Vitals/HR[4]   Time    02:00:12
/Vitals/HR[5]   Value   84 
/Vitals/HR[5]   Time    02:10:12
```

As you can see, the `BP[x]` indexes are correct, but when the node-name changes from "BP" to "HR", the indexes are continuing to increment, and the `HR[x]` index is wrong. I need it to reset the index to get the PROPER XPATH index (*the index of same-named elements*) of the element, not just the index of the element in the parent. I need my output to look like this:

```
/Vitals/BP[1]   Value   120/80
/Vitals/BP[1]   Time    02:00:05
/Vitals/BP[2]   Value   140/90
/Vitals/BP[2]   Time    02:10:01
/Vitals/BP[3]   Value   120/80 
/Vitals/BP[3]   Time    02:15:05
/Vitals/HR[1]   Value   80 
/Vitals/HR[1]   Time    02:00:12
/Vitals/HR[2]   Value   84 
/Vitals/HR[2]   Time    02:10:12
```

Is there a better way to get what I'm looking for? How do I get the proper XPATH index from my nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks for the hard work by John in his answer. His answer DOES work as is (and is faster, according to his testing [see his comment, below]), but I figured out a less complex way to get the index!

The trick is to compare the `local-name(.)` against the local name of the node `$i` during the count() function in our xpath to look like this:

```
for $i in . return count(../../*[. << $i and local-name(.) = local-name($i/..)])
```

The full code now looks like this:

```
DECLARE @x XML = '
    <Vitals>
        <BP>
            <Value>120/80</Value>
            <Time>02:00:05</Time>
        </BP>
        <BP>
            <Value>140/90</Value>
            <Time>02:10:01</Time>
        </BP>
        <BP>
            <Value>120/80</Value>
            <Time>02:15:05</Time>
        </BP>
        <HR>
            <Value>80</Value>
            <Time>02:00:12</Time>
            <Signature>twig</Signature>
        </HR>
        <HR>
            <Value>84</Value>
            <Time>02:10:12</Time>
            <Signature>twig</Signature>
        </HR>
    </Vitals>'
```

---

```
SELECT '/' + child.value('local-name(../..)', 'varchar(max)') + '/' + child.value('local-name(..)', 'varchar(max)') + '[' + child.value('for $i in . return count(../../*[. << $i and local-name(.) = local-name($i/..)])', 'varchar(max)') + ']' AS NodePath
    ,child.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') AS NodeName
    ,child.value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS NodeValue
FROM (
    SELECT @x AS import_data
    ) i
CROSS APPLY i.import_data.nodes('/Vitals/*/*') AS nodes(child)
WHERE LEN(cast(child.query('./*') AS VARCHAR(max))) = 0
```

and outputs as expected:

> /Vitals/BP[1]     Value       120/80
>
> /Vitals/BP[1]     Time        02:00:05
>
> /Vitals/BP[2]     Value       140/90
>
> /Vitals/BP[2]     Time        02:10:01
>
> /Vitals/BP[3]     Value       120/80
>
> /Vitals/BP[3]     Time        02:15:05
>
> /Vitals/HR[1]     Value       80
>
> /Vitals/HR[1]     Time        02:00:12
>
> /Vitals/HR[1]     Signature   twig
>
> /Vitals/HR[2]     Value       84
>
> /Vitals/HR[2]     Time        02:10:12
>
> /Vitals/HR[2]     Signature   twig

Comment: Well done!  Your approach peeked my interest, so I HAD to test it.  After 15 runs each, (I'm quietly pleased that) my approach was 11 to 24% faster (avg 15.353% or 7.21ms).   I'm not clear on all the inner workings of XML, but I suspect the degradation occurs in the count.  Either way, I never even considered the count, and will certainly keep it in my toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Take note of `+ cast( (row_number() over ...`

**Example Update For Dynamic Number of Child Nodes**

```
Select A.NodePath
      ,B.*
 From (
        Select NodePath  = '/'+lvl1.n.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') 
                          +'/'+lvl2.n.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)')
                          +'['
                          + cast(Row_Number() over (Partition By  lvl2.n.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') Order By (Select null)) as varchar(25))
                          +']'
              ,XMLData   = lvl2.n.query('*') 
         From  @X.nodes('Vitals')      lvl1(n)
         Cross Apply lvl1.n.nodes('*') lvl2(n)
      ) A 
 Cross Apply (
                Select NodeName =lvl1.n.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') 
                      ,ItemValue=lvl1.n.value('(.)', 'varchar(max)') 
                 From  A.XMLData.nodes('*') lvl1(n)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
NodePath        NodeName    NodeValue
/Vitals/BP[1]   Value       120/80
/Vitals/BP[1]   Time        02:00:05
/Vitals/BP[2]   Value       140/90
/Vitals/BP[2]   Time        02:10:01
/Vitals/BP[3]   Value       120/80
/Vitals/BP[3]   Time        02:15:05
/Vitals/HR[1]   Value       80
/Vitals/HR[1]   Time        02:00:12
/Vitals/HR[2]   Value       84
/Vitals/HR[2]   Time        02:10:12
```

Comment: Phenominal! Can you explain how this works? I'm a bit confused by the `Partion ...  Order By (Select null)) + 1) / 2`.
FTR, your solution works splededly!

Comment: @TaterJuice Just added a row_number() partitioned by child local name.   If you remove the divide by 2, you would see the actual row number.  Keep in mind this works with two pairs.  If you have sets of 3 then it would be / 3

Comment: Hmm. It seems to work fine even when I add additional, differently named nodes - without changing the divide by 2

Comment: @TaterJuice Yes it would.  I was refering to Value & Time not BP and HR

Comment: @TaterJuice The window functions can be invaluable !  Well worth your time to get comfortble with them  :)

Comment: Hmm... Addin a third node inside the BP and changing to divid by 3 is giving me different results. In an attempt to make it more dynamic, I changed `/ 2` to `/ (child.value('for $i in . return count(../*[.])', 'int') + 1)` but thats not working either... Ideas?

Comment: @TaterJuice Are the nodes consistant?  2 per or 3 per ?

Comment: @TaterJuice One moment, I will make an update to accept variable nodes

Comment: The node-count is dynamic. I'm getting closer with `/ child.value('count(../*)', 'int')` but this is giving my FIRST node an index of 0 instead of 1, when there are more than 2 nodes

Comment: @TaterJuice Remove the Accepted answer while I figure this one out.  In the meantime, perhaps another answer

Comment: I nearly have it. Updated my original post with new info.

Comment: @TaterJuice Take a peek at my updated answer.  Sorry for the delay... wife needed a hand moving a parrot cage

Comment: @TaterJuice Level3 can have a variable number of nodes

Comment: I found a simpler solution comparing node names on count: `for $i in . return count(../../*[. << $i and local-name(.) = local-name($i/..)])`